# What is the recomended way to cache static files on Blazor Server (.NET 7.0)?

Tags: blazor-server-side, browser-cache

I have tried to add ResponseCaching on Program.cs but the browser keeps downloading the same images from the server each time

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
builder.Services.AddResponseCaching();
...
var app = builder.Build();
...
app.UseResponseCaching();
...
app.Run();
```